# PHP assigning date function and accessing class property outside the class problems

Tags: php, class, properties

Braking my head over this.
I’m trying to assign a date() function to a property of foo() class like that.

```
class Foo{
 public $dt = date("F-d-Y H:j:s");

function today(){} //just some empty method
};
$g = new Foo();
echo $g->dt;
```

I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'  //this is date() line

I also tried that.

```
class Foo{
public $dt;

function today(){
echo $this->dt = date("F-d-Y H:j:s");
}
};
$g = new Foo();
$g->today();
```

No errors and everything works fine. So, seems to me, that we can't assign date() to a class property directly.
Please point me to a right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide an initialization of a class property, it has to be a constant, not a function call. If you want to compute the initial value, do it in the class constructor method.

```
class Foo {
    public $dt;

    function __construct() {
        $this->dt = date("F-d-Y H:j:s");
    }
}

$g = new Foo();
echo $g->dt;
```

From the PHP [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.